# Swift - TableView Assert Error: cellForRowAtIndexPath Because of: canEditRowAt()

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, assert

Using the following code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    switch viewControllerCanEdit {
    case .viewControllerThatCanNotEdit:
        return false
    default:
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.reuseIdentifier == "CellThatAllowsEditing" else { return false }
        return true
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following Assertion Error:

> [Assert] Attempted to call -cellForRowAtIndexPath: on the table view
> while it was in the process of updating its visible cells, which is
> not allowed. Make a symbolic breakpoint at
> UITableViewAlertForCellForRowAtIndexPathAccessDuringUpdate to catch
> this in the debugger and see what caused this to occur. Perhaps you
> are trying to ask the table view for a cell from inside a table view
> callback about a specific row? Table view: <UITableView:
> 0x7fd48303ec00; frame = (0 0; 414 896); clipsToBounds = YES;
> autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60000284e070>;
> layer = <CALayer: 0x60000264f340>; contentOffset: {0, -100};
> contentSize: {414, 2765.3333333333335}; adjustedContentInset: {100, 0,
> 83, 0}; dataSource: <TableViewController:
> 0x7fd48281b000>>

I've narrowed down the cause. Supposedly this error is a result of the tableView calling `canEditRowAt()` while it's in the process of updating the data. And because of that, the call to match the `tableView.cellForRow(at:)` doesn't yet exist.

**My question** is; Is there a way to break out of the function if the tableView is updating? Or if there is a better way of trying to match if the cell can be edited based on the cells type?

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to add a property in the data model

```
var canEdit = false
```

maintain it and check it (`dataSourceArray` is the data source array)

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    switch viewControllerCanEdit {
    case .viewControllerThatCanNotEdit:
        return false
    default:
        return dataSourceArray[indexPath.row].canEdit
    }
}
```

Comment: The data model is a `NSFetchedResultsController`. I'm also adding 0-2 additional sections depending on which viewController segued to the current controller. And I have 3 different types of cells. - I'm more so curious why `canEditRowAt` is getting called before the tableView finishes with the cell. And how I can add a safety check so I can keep using something small and clean like `guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? EditableTableViewCell else { return false }; return true`

Comment: Distinguish the cell type the same way as in `cellForRowAt`

Comment: Yes. That works, however I'm still curious why `canEditRowAt` is called before the cell is finished being setup.